# DatasourceRequest always return null when Kendo grid is in PopUp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, popup, kendo-grid

I am trying to open kendo grid in popup on clicking of link. Kendo grid Opens in popup perfectly, but filtering and sorting functionality is not working. I am using server side Operation. When I sort particular column In controller side in DatasourceRequest I always gets value as null.

Any help is highly appreciated..

```
  <div class="panel-body" id="countryImageData">
                    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.GlobalInventoryImages)
                .Name("InventoryCountryImageDetailsGrid")
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(p => p.SmartInventoryID).Hidden().Title("SPC #").HtmlAttributes(new { @id = "CountrySmartInventory_Grid" });
                    columns.Bound(p => p.SubwayProductCode).Width(50).Title("SPC #").HtmlAttributes(new { @id = "CountrySubwayProductCode_Grid" });
                    columns.Bound(p => p.GlobalCaseImageName).Width(100).Title("Case Images").HtmlAttributes(new { @id = "GlobalCaseGraphicName_Grid" }).ClientTemplate(" <a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" class=\"btn-openpdf\" onClick = \"getGlobalImage(this,false,true,true);\">#=GlobalCaseImageName#</a> ");
                    columns.Bound(p => p.GlobalInnerImageName).Width(100).Title("Inner  Images ").HtmlAttributes(new { @id = "GlobalInnerImageName_Grid" }).ClientTemplate(" <a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" class=\"btn-openpdf\" onClick = \"getGlobalImage(this,false,false,true);\">#=GlobalInnerImageName#</a> ");
                    columns.Bound(p => p.CountryNames).Width(100).Title("Country").HtmlAttributes(new { @id = "CountryNames_Grid" });
                })
                                        .Pageable(pager => pager.PageSizes(new int[] { 25, 50, 75, 100 }).Input(true))
                                        .Sortable(e => e.AllowUnsort(true).SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
                                        .Scrollable()
                                        .ColumnMenu()
                                        .NoRecords("No Records")
                                        .Selectable(e => e.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
                                        .Filterable()
                                        .ColumnResizeHandleWidth(10)
                                        .ColumnResizeHandleWidth(10)
                                        .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
                                        .Reorderable(reorder => reorder.Columns(true))
                                        .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "custom-kendo-grid custom-kendo-grid-inv" })
                                        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                        .Ajax()
                                        .ServerOperation(true)
                                        .PageSize(25)
                                                            .Read(read => read.Action("InventoryImage_Read", "Inventory").Data("function onCountryAdditonalData(){ return {subwayProductCode: $('#SubwayProductCode').val()};}"))
                                        )

                    )

                </div>
```

Comment: Perhaps you could show a little code?

Comment: @RaniRadcliff Code added.please see above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With MVC you have to add the following in your dataSource:

```
type: 'aspnetmvc-ajax'
```

for the filter and sort not to be null.  Also, your Action method in your MVC Controller must have parameters set up like so:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> InventoryImage_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest )
```

You didn't post your MVC Controller Action so I wasn't sure if you had that part set up correctly.  I hope this helps.

Comment: In popup,I am not able to type anything in Kendo filter box